# Finding a way to dynamically add entity name prefix to Nested Entity Properties specified in Pageable Sort.Order objects

Tags: hibernate, sorting, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, entity

In my application, I pass the sort parameters from the UI via HTTP Request Params to the a Spring Data Rest application. My JPA Repository Entity has @ManyToOne Entities in it. The data I send back to the UI is retrieved from the properties of these nested entities (employee, contact, businessLine shown below). I created a Pageable object with the sort params coming from the UI. I don't want to have to hardcode the entity alias to the sort params manually in my application. Do you have any ideas how I can do this.

```
Page<BusContact> contacts = busContactRepository.findAll(pageable);
```

The entity..

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BUSCONTACTS")
public class BusContact implements Persistable<String> , Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "id", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("Business Line")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_line_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private BusinessLine businessLine;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Contact contact;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Employee employee;
...
```

The sort params that work

```
employee.employeeNumber: ASC
employee.company: ASC
```

The sort params that don't work

```
employeeNumber: ASC
company: ASC
```

I'm having to manually determine which entity has the sort property and add the entity alias while creating the Sort.Order objects to be passed into Pageable.

```
new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.fromString(sortProps[1].trim()), "employee."+sortProps[0].trim())
```

Similarly for the properties in entities 'contact' and 'businessLine' that I want to sort by.

One of the solutions I was trying was to use repository and entity metadata to determine which entity has the property and then dynamically add the entity name as the alias. But trying to get the metadata has been quite challenging so far. I've tried Repositories, DefaultRepositoryMetadata. Just posting here to see if you have a better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I found is to determine the Entity from the Repository being used and examine the entity fields to determine which one's match the requested sort parameters and then add the respective entity prefix to them.

In order to find the Entity information, one way is to utilize the getDomainClass() protected method of SimpleJpaRepository. But since this method is protected, we can expose those details by extending this class and configuring the application to use our extended implementation of SimpleJpaRepository.

I found the following link detailing how to extend SimpleJpaRepository.

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-into-all-repositories/